# Python - Multiple inheritance: does a keyword exist to execute the method on all ancestors?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Consider:

```
class X:

    def some_method(self):
        print("X.some_method called")

class Y:

    def some_method(self):
        print("Y.some_method called")

class Foo(X,Y):

    def some_method(self):

        super().some_method()
        # plus some Foo-specific work to be done here

foo_instance = Foo()
foo_instance.some_method()
```

Output:

```
X.some_method called
```

Switching the class declaration of Foo to instead be:

```
class Foo(Y,X):
```

Alters the output to:

```
Y.some_method called
```

If I want both ancestor methods to be called I could alter Foo's implementation as:

```
def some_method(self):

    X().some_method()
    Y().some_method()
    # plus some Foo-specific work to be done here
```

This leads to my question.  Is there any uber secret way to cause Python to invoke the method on all ancestors without me doing so explicitly like the code, such as (I'm making up the all_ancestors keyword here - does such a thing actually exist?):

```
def some_method(self):

    all_ancestors().some_method()
    # plus some Foo-specific work to be done here
```

with an expected output of:

```
X.some_method called
Y.some_method called
```

Comment: -1 This is a duplicate for all practical purposes of your previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no secret way to do that.  As I mentioned in your other question, the usual way to do this is not to call all ancestor methods from the single descendant class.  Instead, each class should use `super` to call just *one* ancestor method, namely the next one up the inheritance chain.  If every class in the tree does this (except the topmost base class), then all methods will get called in order.  In other words, Foo should use `super()`, which will call `X`'s method; and then `X` should also use `super()`, which will call `Y`'s method.

To make this work right, it is usually best to have a single topmost class in the inheritance tree.  In your example this would be a class that is the base of both X and Y.  You need such a class to serve as a final stop to the sequence of `super` calling; this base class should *not* call super.  If you just keep calling `super` everywhere, eventually it will try to call up to the base `object` class, and then fail because `object` doesn't provide the method you're trying to call.

Comment: This is a very contrived example (as you can see).  Having said that, in this case the inheritance tree is not Foo -> X -> Y.  It's Foo -> X,Y.  But your answer that there's no uber secret way to invoke the method on both parents answers my question, thanks!

Comment: @MatthewLund: Although Foo inherits from both, the inheritance order (called the "method resolution order") is still `Foo -> X -> Y` because X is inherited before Y.  (You can see this by printing `Foo.__mro__`.)  There always has to be a linear resolution order in order to decide which class's implementation actually gets called.

Comment: see marcins post in your other thread about the use of super and how to properly use it ... it is good advice...

Comment: Actually, the topmost class can call `super`, but you need an exception handler to catch the resulting exception.

Comment: Thanks Bren, didn't realize that the linear resolution order came into play.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide `X` & `Y` with a common base class or mix-in, this should work:

```
class ISomeMethod:
    def some_method(self):
        pass

class X(ISomeMethod):
    def some_method(self):
        print("X.some_method called")
        super(X, self).some_method()

class Y(ISomeMethod):
    def some_method(self):
        print("Y.some_method called")
        super(Y, self).some_method()
```

`some_method` should then be called in the order which you declare the base classes in `Foo`.